# Get Data in QODBC and Convert it in decimal number

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to get the data of the amount and convert it as a decimal number.

I encounter a problem that the value of amount that have a decimal number is being round off. Example: the amount that I need is `amount = 123.5` but the value that I'm getting is `124` .

```
   If Me.chkEnterBill.Checked = True Then
         Dim amount As Decimal
         amount = CDec(Val("amount"))
         strSelect = "SELECT Txnnumber, payeeentityreffullname, txndate, bankaccountreffullname" _
         & ",amount, refnumber, appliedtotxnrefnumber, appliedtotxntxndate, appliedtotxnamount, memo from billpaymentcheckline WHERE" _
         & " refnumber BETWEEN '" & CInt(Me.txtRefFR.Text) & "' AND '" & CInt(Me.txtRefTO.Text) & "' AND" _
         & " bankaccountreffullname='" & Me.lblBankName.Text & "'ORDER BY refnumber"

         Try

              Dim conChk As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(My.Settings.strConn)
              conChk.Open()

              Dim cmdChk As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(strSelect, conChk)
              cmdChk.CommandType = CommandType.Text

              Dim daChk As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(cmdChk)
              daChk.Fill(dsCVI, "tblvoucheritem")


              With dgvCV
                   .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
                   .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
                   .DataSource = dsCVI.Tables("tblvoucheritem")
                   .ReadOnly = True
              End With

              daChk.Dispose()
              cmdChk.Dispose()
              conChk.Close()
              Me.rbCheck.Enabled = True
              Me.rbCV.Enabled = True

        Catch ex As Exception
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
              Me.rbCheck.Enabled = False
              Me.rbCV.Enabled = False

        Finally

              End Try
              Me.stpLoadBar.Value = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

In your database check the data type (and the values)  for the column **amount** in the table **billpaymentcheckline**. Either the data type is NOT decimal or the values are rounded.

Also check the grid view column corresponding to "amount" in your markup.

**Edit:**

and the code for : dsCVI. Is that a DataSet ? Basically where ever you are storing the data you retrieve from your QODBC db. See if there is DataTable involved ... if so the DataTypes that are set on that Table.(Based on your comments it appears that this was your issue as the DataTypes in your DataSet did not match whats in the DB)

Comment: how will i fix this kind of problem ?

Comment: my database is QODBC

Comment: @Maine did you check your DB ? It was the first thing that I would do to Troubleshoot the issue. If issue with datatype then schema needs to change. Usually done by DBA's. Let me know what you find.

Comment: in my database the exact value is 1234.60 but when i run my program the value that im getting is 1235

Comment: i just want to get the exact amount which is 1234.60 . I've tried to convert it in decimal but i think i made the wrong syntax that's why im getting 1235

Comment: show me the code for : dsCVI. Is that a DataSet ? BAsically where ever you are storing the data you retrieve from your QODBC db. See if there is DataTable involved ... if so the DataTypes that are set on that Table. Similarly for the GridView column definitions.

Comment: thank you sir for the help . i find the exact answer to the problem . in my dataset the amount have been declared as integer that's why i can't get the decimal number of it . ive changed it in decimal . Thank you

Comment: @Maine I edited the answer to add the DataSet DataType checking. Please check and accept as answer if it solved your issue.